# Get ID of NSMutableArray

Tags: swift, get, nsmutablearray

I have NSMutableArray called timelineData

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        let idForDelete:AnyObject! = timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
        println(idForDelete)
    }
}
```

When I execute this code in debugger I receive this:

```
<ClassName:gGYnstSagn:(null)> {
    content = "iosdfjgijdsiofgjisd oifg jiosdfgi sdfig j";
    title = ahgahahah;
    userid = "6rOBfCHtcu";
}
```

How I can get the ID "gGYnstSagn" of ClassName ?

Comment: I don't think you can access that outside the debugging context, and I'm not sure you could use it for anything even if you had it. What's your goal?

Comment: how to access inside the debugging context content, title and userid i tryed with dot notation but unsuccessfull